# Designing REST API

Tags: rest

Currently, I have this resource:

> **GET** /orders/{orderNumber}/{provisionId}/{taxYear}/docs

This returns the given order's documents. An `Order` is identified by three numbers: `orderNumber`, `provisionId` and `taxYear`. That is the primary key in the database.

I think this is a bad resource design and I want to change it, instead of use different path params for each composite primary key's part.

Is there a standard to model this kind of resources? I don't know how to manage entities that have composite id.

I have thought to do this:

> **GET** /orders/{orderNumber,provisionId,taxYear}/docs

This would be one path param for the order identificator and server would split it to obtain each part.

Another choice I have thought is by query params:

> **GET** /orders/docs?orderNumber=1234&provisionId=1054&taxYear=2015

But I think the last one wouldn't be semantically correct in REST architecture, since in this case query params are required and are not " search filter" params.

Is there any standard to do this? Which is the better choice?

Thanks

Comment: **GET** `/orders/docs/{taxYear}/{orderNumber}/{provisionId}` seems to make more sense if docs are the only thing to retrieve by those params.  I assume `taxYear` and `orderNumber` are 1:many and `orderNumber` and `provisionId` are also 1:many in this case.  if one or both of those assumptions is false, then a different ordering would make more sense.

Comment: A compound resource identifier is possible for sure. At least JAX-RS allows for a construct like `@Path("{first}-{second}/{third}") public void doSomething(@PathParam("first") String first, @PathParam("second") String second, @PathParam("third") String third, Object payload) ...`. Furthermore regex expressions are also allowed for path parameters. See also [a trivial example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-path-uri-matching-example/). As per your question: REST does not define how an endpoint URL has to look like, it just has to be compliant with the HTTP protocol

Comment: URI semantics is irrelevant in REST. The only thing that matters is how the clients get the URI. Any "standards" regarding URI semantics will be opinion-based.